# iOS Bluetooth printer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, printing, zebra-printers

Does anybody suggest a mobile printer able to print receipt with a good SDK to interface wireless an iOS application adhoc developed ? The printer should be small and should use rechargeable batteries for field use.
I cannot use wifi because not always a trusted access point (customer premises) is available, so I think to use Bluetooth, but of course any suggestion is welcome !

FYI I already checked Zebra printers SDK for iOS but it seems able to print only using a TCP/IP address, it means (for as I know) I should use wifi. In my case the application should be used in the field from an iPad connected with cellular network. In iPad there is no hot-spot and not always there is an available wifi access point tho connect the iPad and the printer the the same network to use TCP/IP addresses. That is the reason I'm guessing the last chance should be bluetooth.

Comment: I'm 90% sure iphone's bluetooth is none of use, it can be used only for gaming and bluetooth headphone. Nothing else except it.

Comment: Bluetooth can be used with any hardware that has been approved thru Apple's MFI program

Comment: Zebra just came out with an MFi printer, just fyi... http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/printers/printer-type/mobile/mz-series.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS5 does not support Bluetooth printing.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

Have you considered VPN via WEP to a network printer?

Alternatively some printers can be set up with their own email address. PDF attachments can be sent via this address to be printed. These emails can be sent encrypted.

I know that this isn't the IDEAL answer, but it is likely to work for the time being until iOS is properly updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think there is no way to print using Bluetooth and, in my case, there is no network for using AirPrint trought wifi because the user will be a tecnician in the field (at customers premises)!that has to release a report as soon as he completes the task.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have Bluetooth printer for IOS device, it is Apple MFI approved

see details from this URL http://www.bluebamboo.com/other_file/P25i%20Datasheet%20%28EN%29%20v1.0%2009-Oct-2011.pdf

Comment: Do you have more info about interface ? (dock connector / bluetooth). Do you have a specific iOS SDK ?

Comment: @Davi.Wang ..Hi..  Are you used any IOS SDK to connect with bluetooth printer? please share your ideas it will help me...thanks...

Comment: I m in requirement to print to a Bluetooth Printer from iPad . Plz let me know how can I use this printer . Do we need to use any SDK ?

Comment: This link is no more available.

Answer (score 3):

I know you already accepted an answer, but here's another one:  have the technician bring their own wireless base station (AirPort Express perhaps) and create his own wireless network (that won't have internet access, but that's not needed) with appropriate security.  Then you can use any HP wireless capable printer and have the iOS device and the printer connect to the wifi network created by the wireless access point (which should be set with DHCP to vend IP addresses in a non-routable range like 192.168.x.x, obviously).

Comment: Yes that could be a solution also if the Technician has to carry out another (small) device: the router. The router battery needs to be always charged and when you use the Wifi you cannot access internet unless you add a SIM in the router so for each technician we need 2 SIMs (iPad + Router) because not always  he/she needs to print. About printer for as I know there are no "portable" HP printer. All need to user power outlet. Thanks anyway. Dario

Comment: False, they do make a battery powered portable printer.

Answer (score 3):

We also have a Bluetooth printer that is MFI certified along with an easy to understand iOS SDK. Please take a look at the EZPay App on the Appstore. The app's currently in Japanese (fir one of our clients) but the description explain a little about the printer. I'm currently traveling at the moment, but if you shoot me an email from the contact info on the App Store. I can get a few other things out to you. Cheers... B

Answer (score 0):

No need to develop a full blown SDK, check out Mobi Print.  it has the Zebra sdk already implemented and connects to any webservice or ODBC database.  It also has stored label/receipt formats in there app so just upload your format and should be good to go.

[here is link for Mobi Print](http://www.arrowheadphx.com/mobi-print/)