# How to use bluetooth for printing in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

I am trying to create an iPhone application in which I can connect to a bluetooth printer and print .Is anyone aware that if its possible? As far as I am aware for printing we can use AirPrint which uses wi-fi. but any idea how we can use bluetooth.I mean connecting to a printer using bluetooth and send the content to the printer using bluetooth for printing.

Comment: possible duplicate of  [old Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10384177/2407907)

Comment: you can also check  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4820371?start=0&tstart=0