# iOS bluetooth printer implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm a newbie in iOS. I want to know if there's any possibility to do printing at a portable bluetooth printer from iPhone app?

[iOS Bluetooth printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384177/ios-bluetooth-printer)
The thread above said it's not possible but it's two years old. Is there any chance we could do it now?

Comment: Its stated that ... Unfortunately iOS5 does not support Bluetooth printing. which printer are u using ? you can other details

Comment: it's a portable bluetooth given by my client. I integrated it to Android and trying to do the same thing in iOS. I don't have any information about the printer as I don't have the manual. Google the brand doesn't return anything, seems like it's self assembled printer.

Comment: printer model no? name?

Comment: http://www.wpt-3.com/home/

This is the printer website, that's the only information I could find.

Comment: is that printer compatible ios.. its shows only windows mobile n android

Comment: I believe it's not. But even it's supporting iOS is it possible to connect and print via bluetooth?

Comment: @user2535051: I also had the same requirement, did you implement printing feature with bluetooth? If so, can you please share me the info.

Comment: No I did not implement this feature in iOS but only android. Let me know if you're able to do that. Thanks.